# Shorter/alternate version of refrigerator

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario

## English

Is there a shorter or more common word for `refrigeradora` in Mexico and the southern parts of the US? I find it a cumbersome and difficult word to say in Spanish.

---

## Español

Hay otra manera de decir `refrigerador` en el español de Mexico y del sur de los EEUU? Es muy difícil y me cuesta mucho decirlo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Monterrey, Mexico in informal speech we just say "**refri**", however the RAE doesn't have an entry for it.

> La comida está en el refri.

I'm not sure if it is used in all places of Mexico but according to this [question](http://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111028171340AAwMLSm) (Yahoo! Answers Mexico) and its answers it might be used in other places of Mexico.

Comment: I can say refri it's indeed used in other Mexican states (at least I know of Chihuahua and Aguascalientes), so I'd say it's fairly global Mexican wide.

Comment: *refri* is used in Jaliso, Mexico as well.

Comment: I have heard *refri* in Nicaragua as well.

Comment: Yeah, we say *refri* in the DF as well.

Comment: _refri_ is also used in Chile.

Comment: Also used in Argentina

Answer (score 5):

In Spain we don't say "refrigerador" but "frigorífico" or, more commonly, "nevera", which is short enough. I don't know if it works for Mexico, though.

I guess you can shorten "frigorífico" with "frigo", although I think you won't hear that very often.

Comment: Personally, I use "frigo" quite often, but it's very informal. "Frigorífico" it's as difficult to say (or even more) as "refrigerador", so it's not very helpful for the OP, I guess. "Nevera" is far easier, an used a lot in Spain, but I have no idea if it's used at all in Mexico or the US.

Comment: En Barcelona, "nevera" es mucho más popular que "frigo".

Comment: +1 for suggesting `nevera`. `Frigorífico` is mostly used, at least in Colombia, to refer to really big (industrial-type) refrigerators. Home refrigerators are called `neveras` and I don't think I've heard a shorter name than that.

Answer (score 1):

refrigeradora, refrigerador, refrí, nevera, heladera all are the same appliance.

That are all possible ways to say the same, (I think) the thing is that the name of this appliance have different names on different regions. Refri is the short version for refrigerador/a but its starting to be used in places where is was called heladera.

There is no short version.

Frigorífico relates to a big industrial complex (usually for things preserved with could) but also in some countries (one or two) may be used for the name of the appliance.

Frigo can be used as a short version of frigorifico despite its mening (appliance or industrial complex)

Frigobar is one of those refrigerators that are really small usually found on motels, the ones that have space for a couple of bottles an a pizza (no more than a meter hight).

---

refrigeradora, refrigerador, refrí, nevera, heladera son el mismo aparato.

Esas son todas la formas posibles de decir lo mismo (a mi entender), el nombre varia según el país.
Refri es la versión corta de refrigerador/a aunque esta comenzando a ser utilizada en países donde se le llama comúnmente heladera.

No hay versión corta para la palabra.

Frigorífico comúnmente se utiliza para describir complejos industriales donde se preservan cosas con frio, no obstante es utilizada como nombre para describir el mismo aparato (uno o dos países).

Frigo es utilizado como la versión corta de frigorifico sin importar el significado real de la palabra.

Frigobar es una de esas aparatos que no llega a un metro de altura, comúnmente vistas en moteles.

Answer (score -1):

`Frigo` is the most usual term in Spain.

Comment: Really? I'm not sure about the rest of Spain but at least in Galicia we always say "nevera".

Comment: @kelmer I often hear "frigo" and "nevera" in Spain. Probably more "frigo" because "nevera" is also used for a cool box for a picnic and the term can be ambiguous sometimes.

Comment: Just because is the most used term in a geographical region don't means is the correct way, or the most comprehensive way to answer the question

Comment: you can apply this to the rest of the answers